# Equity market inflow meaning

Tags: stock-markets

Recently a lot of finance articles have talked about there being $25B in inflows to US equity markets since the election...what does that mean?

If for every buyer, there's a seller, doesn't that also mean that there were $25B in outflows in the same time period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose I purchase $10,000 worth of a particular share today.

If the person(s) I am purchasing the shares from paid $9,000 for those shares, then I replacing their $9,000 investment with my $10,000 investment.  This is a net *inflow* of $1,000 into the market.

Similarly, if the person(s) I am purchasing the shares from paid $11,000 for those shares, then their $11,000 investment is being replace by my $10,000 investment.  This is a net *outflow* of $1,000 out of the market.

The aggregate of all such inflows and outflows in the net inflow/outflow into the market over a given period of time.  (Here we are ignoring the effects of new share issues.)

Comment: Agreed - the change in market value is the change in value in between the time of the current transaction, and the previous transaction. The transaction itself, as pointed out by the asker, involves someone selling for $x, and someone buying for $x (no net change in and of itself, only a change when compared to the value of the company at the time of the seller's original purchase).

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Yes - essentially the gross P&L on the sellers ledger.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to get at is the concept of "cash on the sidelines".  In your scenario, you buy $10k worth of stock from someone who now has $10k worth of cash.  There is no change in cash in the system.  The same amount of cash is still "on the sidelines", right?

Comment: @cph2117 The cash received by the seller will only be "on the sidelines" if it was not reinvested.  New cash coming into the market will not affect inflows in the way you are imagining.  This is because it will simply replace existing equity at a new "book value", and the existing equity has been purchased at a cost.  In my example, the $10,000 I have invested may have been "sitting on the sidelines".  Inflows are all about equity, not cash on the sidelines.

Comment: So it would seem then that "cash on the sidelines" is somewhat of a misnomer, and all inflows really means is that there are now more investors willing to pay more for a stock than it was originally purchased for.

Comment: @cph2117 Cash on the sidelines is certainly an influential factor on the markets.  I'd say that "inflows" is probably more of a misnomer.  Maybe "through flow" would be a better title.

Comment: So just to clarify, on this old question… are people saying “equity market inflows” is a synonym for “realized gains” ?

Answer (score 1):

> If for every buyer, there's a seller, doesn't that also mean that there were $25B in outflows in the same time period?

Yes for every buyer there is a seller. The inflows are not being talked in that respect.

> about there being $25B in inflows to US equity markets since the election...what does that mean?

Lets say the index was at X. After a month the index is at X+100. 
So lets say there are only 10 companies listed. So if the Index has moved X to X+100, then share price S1 has moved to S1+d1. So if you sum all such shares/trades that have increased in value, you will get what in inflow.

In the same period there could be some shares that have lost value. i.e. the price or another share was S2 and has moved to S2-d2. The sum of all such shares/trades that have decreased in value, you will get outflow.

The terms are Gross outflow, Gross inflow. In Net terms for a period, it can only be Inflow or outflow; depending on the difference between inflow and outflow.

The stats are done day to day and aggregated for the time period required.

So generally if the index has increased, it means there is more inflow and less outflow.

At times this analysis is also done on segments, FI's inflow is more compared to outflow or compared to inflow of NBFI or Institutional investors or Foreign participants etc.

Answer (score 0):

An equity market inflow is when the market is bullish and 'Buy' volumes precede 'Sell volumes'. Opposite for outflow. 
As a transaction, there is a buy and sell. In your example, the net value out of the transactions is nil but what makes the net flow an 'outflow' or 
'inflow' depends on the difference between the 'long' positions vs 'short' positions. I hope the explanation helps.

Answer (score -1):

Inflows to the US equity market can come from a variety of sources; for instance:

- You were paid a year-end bonus and decided to invest it in US equities instead of foreign equities, bonds, savings or debt reduction.
- You sold foreign equities, bonds, or other non-US equities and decided to invest in US equities.
- You decided a better use of cash in a savings account, CD or money market fund, was to invest in US equities.

> If for every buyer, there's a seller, doesn't that also mean that
>   there were $25B in outflows in the same time period?

Not necessarily. Generally, the mentions we see of inflows and outflows are net; that is, the gross investment in US equities, minus gross sales of US equities equals net inflows or outflows.

The mere fact that I sold my position in, say, Caterpillar, doesn't mean that I had to re-invest in US equities. I may have bought a bond or a CD or a house.

Because of fluctuations in existing stocks market value, bankruptcies and new issues, US equities never are and never will be a zero-sum game.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the primary point of the question: if 1,000,000 people each bought $25,000 of US stocks [totaling $25B], doesn't that mean that they bought those stocks from people who were selling them? Doesn't that mean that no net money was actually invested, because the people entering the market took the place of people leaving the market? [there are counterpoints to this, but I am attempting to rephrase the OP's question to highlight what is missing from this answer].

Comment: No; the people who sold didn't necessarily reinvest the proceeds of the sale outside of US equities; they may have bought other US equity stocks, for example.

Comment: You may be missing the point - when they bought other US equity stocks, didn't they buy them from people who already held them? The question becomes: Why is the following untrue: "Every time you buy stock, you buy from someone who is selling, and therefore no new value ever enters the equity market"?

Comment: It is untrue for exactly the reasons in my answer. Not all money invested must *necessarily* come from the proceeds of sales of *US equities*. It may have come from a bonus, sales of bonds, sales of foreign equities, sale of a house, etc., etc.

Comment: Assume you are the only person in the world who owns US stock - you own the entire US equity market (congratulations). Now I buy all of that stock from you. I use money from my job to buy that stock (I must have a very good job). Has any value entered the US equity market? Before, you owned everything, and now I own everything. Either way, the same stocks exist, the same companies driving value for those stocks exist. Has new value entered the market in this case? [even though I used money from outside the market]. Extended: what if someone buys the stock from me afterwards; is this different?

Comment: I own a stock I paid 6$ for.  You buy it from me for 10$.  4$ just got added.

Comment: @Ross Thanks, that's part of what I was driving at - but the key is that the value is created not from me buying the stock at a higher price, the value is created from the underlying company itself.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I'm curious to your reasoning behind "the value is created from the underlying company itself."  Very rarely is this the case...especially in the type of articles the OP mentioned.

Comment: @Ross I work from the assumption of market efficiency - that stocks are priced according to their true value, to the best of available public information. So when you bought your stock for $6, the company you invested in was worth $6 / share. When I bought for $10, the company was worth $10 / share. Neither you nor I impacted the true value of the company by our purchase - because we didn't give the company any additional cashflow. Instead, our purchases *signaled* the value of the company as determined by the market at that time. That is, since the value changed from $6 to $10, I paid $10.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon You still added $4 to the market - not the company.  Anyway, I believe the article(s) the OP was referring to were about inflows from different classes of assets into ETFs.  In these examples the net add was 0; the money just moved from one asset class to the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49620/discussion-between-ross-and-grade-eh-bacon).